# Count the number of spaces in text excluding indent

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to count the number of spaces in content of a log file.

I referred to multiple websites and the possible solution provided is as below:

```py
datafile = input("enter the file name:")

k=0

with open(datafile, 'r') as openedfile:
    for line in openedfile:
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
                for letter in i:
                    if(letter.isspace):
                        k=k+1
print (k)
```

But this code prints the number of letters in the file.

I tried the below code:

```py
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

k = 0

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
                for a in line:
                    if (a.isspace()) == True:
                        k = k+1
print("Occurrences of blank spaces:")
print(k)
```

This is treating the indent (the end of the first line and star of the first line) as a space.

I expect the code to print only the number of spaces in the content of the file (excluding the indent from line to line)

Comment: How big is your file? Start small like 2 lines and debug your code, then try with actual file size. It seems to me that you will crack it on your own. Just do finite and easy to debug tests.

Comment: If you are just interested in spaces you could do something like `k += line.strip().count(' ')`

Comment: @Heike That won't count tabs, for example.

Comment: @Selcuk  That's why I mentioned "just spaces" in my comment.

Comment: @Heike Agreed, but the OP is currently using `.isspace()` which detects all whitespace characters. The method you suggested is not an equivalent.

Comment: @JohnHennig: Thank you for the correction. When i mentioned indent I was referring to the break that comes at end of the line to start the second line which was counted as space in my code.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev: My file was just 2 lines. it actually had 8 spaces(manually counted) but it counted 9 as the break at the end of the line was counted as a space.

Comment: @Rao, thanks for letting us know, it's good that you are using standard testing and debugging techniques, it is always much easier to find a problem in a smaller manageable piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

```
total_spaces = 0

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    total_spaces = sum([len(list(filter(lambda c: c == ' ', line))) for line in f])

print(total_spaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of items that result from the `.split()` method applied to spaces (minus one because there will be one more item than spaces).

```py
n_space = len(open('text.txt', 'r').read().split(' ')) - 1
```

With the `text.txt` file below, the code successfully counts 7 spaces.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

**Edit**

If you have multiple separators that you want to treat as spaces (like double spaces or tabs), just replace them by simple spaces before splitting and counting

```py
text = open('text.txt', 'r').read().replace('  ', ' ').replace('\t', ' ')
n_spaces = len(text.split(' ')) - 1
```

Comment: this worked flawless. Do you see in what occasion there is a chance this may fail? considering lengthy paras or double spaces or tabs or indents or breaks?

Comment: and also i would like get a better idea on logic of using -1

Comment: I edited the answer to treat the double-spaces (or any other separator) case. If the indent is made with tabs and you do not want to count it as space, do not replace them and they will not be counted (like breaks).

Comment: For the minus-one logic: consider the string `"Hello, world!"`. Splitting results in a list `["Hello,", "world!"]` of length 2 (one more item than spaces). Minus one outputs the correct number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the leading and trailing spaces using [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
...
for a in line.strip():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex --> `re.findall(r"\s", line.strip())`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

with open(filename) as infile:
    print(sum(len(re.findall(r"\s", line.strip())) for line in infile))
```

- `\s` --> for space in text